# Extremely slow moving of data VBA - Alternatives

Tags: excel, vba

I have this working code which copies data in specific columns to a new file.

```
Sub GetFileCopyData()
   Dim Fname As String
   Dim SrcWbk As Workbook
   Dim DestWbk As Workbook

   Set DestWbk = ThisWorkbook

   Application.Calculation = xlManual
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Sheets("Data").UsedRange.ClearContents

   Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*), *.csv*", Title:="Select a File")
   If Fname = "False" Then Exit Sub
   Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname)

   SrcWbk.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Data").Range("A:A")
   SrcWbk.Sheets(1).Range("E:E").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Data").Range("B:B")
   SrcWbk.Sheets(1).Range("M:M").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Data").Range("C:C")
   SrcWbk.Sheets(1).Range("AD:AD").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Data").Range("D:D")
   SrcWbk.Sheets(1).Range("AF:AF").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Data").Range("E:E")
   SrcWbk.Sheets(1).Range("DA:DA").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Data").Range("F:F")
   SrcWbk.Sheets(1).Range("AEG:AEG").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Data").Range("G:G")
   SrcWbk.Sheets(1).Range("AEM:AEM").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Data").Range("H:H")

   SrcWbk.Close False

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

This runs extremely slowly. I've already tried turning screen updating off etc. I read that the following is quicker than copying, which is slow.

```
Range("A1:Z100").value = Range("A101:Z200").value
```

Can anyone please tell me how to implement this? I tried using this code but it ended up being blank:

```
SrcWbk.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Value = DestWbk.Sheets("Data").Range("A:A").Value
```

Comment: You've got the order mixed up. `DestWbk.Sheets("Data").Range("A:A").Value = SrcWbk.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Value `. Note - perhaps consider using Power Query / Get & Transform for this.

Comment: You may also want to turn off events, maybe you have some events getting triggered with the paste.

Comment: `Transposing` is another option you can look at

Comment: What version of Excel is it?

Comment: @Andreas 2010 excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're copying is values, rather than copying the entire column, which is very resource intensive (effectively you're copying 1048576 cells) you could try implementing a lastrow statement and only copy the used range of the column. This could drastically reduce your runtime depending on how many values you have. Something amongst the lines of:

```
Sub copy()
Dim lastr As Long
lastr = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet2.Range("A1:A" & lastr).Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lastr).Value
End Sub
```

To adapt your code you should replace the following line:

```
SrcWbk.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Data").Range("A:A")
```

With this:

```
lastr = SrcWbk.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
DestWbk.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & lastr).value = SrcWbk.Sheets(1).Range("A" & lastr).value
```

Please note if your column lengths vary, you should redo the lastr calculation for every column. If all your columns are the same length (All ending on the same row), then using the first calculation for every column will do.

Comment: Thank you for this - I am a little unsure how to implement this is in my above code though. Would it replace this line? SrcWbk.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Data").Range("A:A")

Comment: @Jimmy I have updated my answer and adapted it to your situation. Any questions feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your requirement is just extracting specific columns from CSV file, then [Get & Transform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-transform-in-excel-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de) should be the best fit rather than VBA solution.

Yet another option is to use Microsoft Text Driver via ADO in VBA.

Comment: Although this may help OP, a answer that relies on a link to work is not a good answer. Copy the parts that is valid here to make your answer work even if the link goes away.

Comment: OP will need the Power Query add-in since it's Excel 2010 per the latest comment.